# JavaCV — ошибка подключения библиотеки

Tags: java, ubuntu, eclipse, opencv, native

Пытаюсь установить и настроить *JavaCV* и *OpenCV* на *ubuntu 14.04*.

Устанавливал по [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/204638/) и по официальной [инструкции](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).
Работаю в *Eclipse*.

В свойствах проекта в пункте *Run/Debug Settings* в поле *VM arguments* добавил строчку:

```
-Djava.library.path="/home/ant/opencv-3.0.0/lib
```

Пытаюсь запустить код из примера с официального сайта:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String filename = null;
        try {
            filename = bf.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        File file = new File(filename);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        IplImage image = cvLoadImage(filename);
        if (image != null) {
            cvSmooth(image, image);
            cvSaveImage(filename, image);
            cvReleaseImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Сам файл находит, но вот функцию `cvLoadImage()` не выполняет, а программа вылетает и выводит в консоль:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/ant/opencv-3.0.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with `execstack -c <libfile>`, or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's highly recommended that you fix the library with `execstack -c <libfile>`, or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

перевод:

исправьте эту библиотеку, выполнив:

```
$ execstack -c /home/ant/opencv-3.0.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0
```

либо добавив (видимо, в то же поле *vm arguments*) строку `-z noexecstack`.

---

во втором пункте (после «либо») изложена лишь моя догадка: я не знаю, как в *eclipse* линкуются библиотеки и где можно добавить параметры для этой линковки.

Comment: Спасибо. Выполнил через терминал:
execstack -c /home/ant/opencv-3.0.0/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0
И теперь выполняется без ошибок.